# Value of Date attribute of entity for Responsebuilder is set to null in the json

Tags: java, json, date, extjs, jax-rs

I'm sending a list of objects to my frontend in extjs.
But in the recieved json all attributes which had type Date are null.
A passeded the  List as entity to the responsebuilder and call build().
All objects and attributes are recieved except the ones of type Date.

Is the response builder able to handle date attributes? 
If not is there a possibility to enable it, or do i have to switch to String representations?

best greetings and many thanks in advance,
OS

Comment: What's actually happening? We need a little more detail to be able to offer any help. You're basically just saying "it's not working". What's not working? What supposed to happen? What is actually happening?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how you're currently storing your dates in the JSON, but keep in mind that [JSON spec](https://www.json.org/) and [this summary](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_data_types.htm) say that there is no inherent Date object that you can store.

Generally speaking, the proper way of sending dates in JSON are with an [ISO 8601 Date format](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003169814.htm). [This tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-date-toisostring-function/) shows how you can get a String that fits the ISO 8601 format.

The reason this is usually the desirably way of storing dates is because it is standardized, and you (or anyone else) can easily convert from this string to a date object (and back again if needed).